# My timed rule wont fire Drools 6.1.0.Final

Tags: drools

I have the two rules.  This is with Drools 6.1.0.Final

```
rule "HandleSomeEvent"
salience 5
no-loop
when
    $eventA  : SomeEvent()
then
    MyClass.handleSomeEvent($eventA); 
end


rule "HandleSomeEventRetry"
    timer(int: 15m 15m)  
    no-loop
    when
        $eventA  : SomeEvent()
    then
        MyClass.handleSomeEvent($eventA);
end
```

Testing of these rules worked without issue in Drools 5.1.1 but I am attempting to refactor to 6.1.0.Final.  In my test class I set up a KieSession

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();

    KieBaseConfiguration kBaseConfig = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    kBaseConfig.setOption(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY);
    KieBase kBase = kContainer.newKieBase(kBaseConfig);

    KieSessionConfiguration kSessionConfig =   ks.newKieSessionConfiguration();
    kSessionConfig.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));

    ksession = kBase.newKieSession(kSessionConfig, null);

    SessionPseudoClock clock = ksession.getSessionClock();
    ksession.setGlobal("MyClass", MyClass);
```

I have tests in this unit test that verify all the rules fire when their events come through, and they all pass but that timed retry event.  My attempt to test the handle event and the retry is as follows

```
    SomeEvent e...
    AgendaEventListener ael = mock(AgendaEventListener.class);
    ksession.addEventListener(ael);
    ksession.insert(e);
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    clock.advanceTime(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    ArgumentCaptor<AfterMatchFiredEvent> amfe = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(AfterMatchFiredEvent.class);
    verify(ael, times(2)).afterMatchFired(amfe.capture());
```

When testing this with 5.1.1 I could also grab the events from the ArgumentCaptor and verify the name of the individual rules that fired.  1st being the initial and second being the timed retry.  However with 6.1.0.Final only a single Match is even fired.  I cannot find any documentation to support this, but have timed events been greatly altered in 6.1?  I have put in debug lines to verify that the event is still there before and after the advance of time, but the timed event will not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a change, as (IIRC) the Drools team appeared to dislike the resulting effect and/or the incompletely defined semantics of timers running while the Rule Engine was *not* active. (Note that you can call `session.fire*()` repeatedly on a session.)

On the move to 6.x, the decision was made to suspend the firing of activations of timer-controlled rules while the engine was not running.

You could (using your rules but with a String for a fact):

```
        kieSession.insert( "Some fact" );
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println("sleep");
        Thread.sleep( 8000 );
        System.out.println("wake-up");
        kieSession.fireUntilHalt();
```

You'll observe that the firing of "retry" that falls into the sleep gap is delayed until after wake-up (and fails to honour the times defined in the timer).

But all works well if you call fireUntilHalt right away. You may have to add another mechanism for a graceful shutdown.

Comment: Thanks.  Just had to add another ksession.fireAllRules() after the clock.advanceTime to trigger my retry rule.